# In Azure DevOps YML pipeline, how to mandate template call?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-extensions, azure-pipelines-decorator

I have a template to perform some post build(end of the pipeline) checks. This check must happen in a build, after few jobs successfully finished.

I want to ensure, template call must be the last job in main pipeline and no control to author to skip. How to mandate template usage ?

Because this template based checks not applicable to all pipelines with in Azure DevOps organization.

Is it possible to use template as a decorator backend and conditionally inject it into selected pipelines in a organization ?

Does decorator support parametrization ?

Comment: Take a look at [Security through templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/security/templates?view=azure-devops) - you can enforce the pipeline to extend specific template with environment checks. I guess that would only work if the pipeline includes `deployment` job.

Comment: I tried enforce the pipeline to extend specific template with resource  checks, it did't work, what is environment checks ?

Comment: I tried enforce the pipeline to extend specific template through agent pool "Approvals and checks", it is working. When i tried same through service connection, it is not working.